# Por que "atriz" e não "atora"?

Tags: etimologia, uso-de-palavras, feminino-masculino

O feminino de:

- *cantor* é [*cantora*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/cantora)
- *redator* é *[redatora](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/redatora)*
- *produtor* é *[produtora](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/produtora)*

Dentre vários outros exemplo de femininos que quando vêm do masculino terminado em -or viram -ora.

Por que para o caso do *ator*, a palavra no feminino não é *atora*?

Comment: Estranho é que em alguns casos, como _embaixador_ e _imperador_ os femininos são _embaixatriz_ e _imperatriz_, mas como aponta [@Earthliŋ](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/868/163) _cantor_ e _produtor_ admitem _cantora_ e _produtora_

Comment: @gmauch bem lembrado, esses exemplos não me passaram pela cabeça na hora de criar a pergunta

Comment: [Palavras que terminam em *‑triz*](http://www.palavras-que.com/terminam-em-triz) — mas não [a *perdiz*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/perdiz). :)

Comment: @tchrist O site do teu link morreu. Vou apagar-te o comentário.

Comment: @gmauch *embaixatriz* e *imperatriz* **não** são femininos de embaixador e imperador. O correto é: *embaixadora* e *imperadora*, respectivamente. Porém, por usucapião do erro, alguns gramático aceitam estes erros, os puristas repudiam.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr [A resposta do Centaurus], abaixo, (https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/870/163) trata deste caso que falaste. Se tiveres algo a adicionar a este respeito podes criar tua resposta!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A palavra *atriz* vem do latim *actrix, -īcis*.

> Por que para o caso do ator, a palavra no feminino não é atora?

Nesse caso acho que é uma questão de etimologia.

---

No caso de *cantora*, também tem uma forma semelhante:

> **cantatriz**
>   [Do lat. *cantatrice*.]
>   *substantivo feminino*
>
> 1. Cantora profissional; cantora.
>
> <sup>Fonte: Aurélio,  5ª edição</sup>

No caso de *produtor*, têm *produtora* e *produtriz* e acho que se usam as duas formas em contextos diferentes:

- *produtora*
  Empresa especializada na produção de filme, video ou programa de rádio.
- *produtriz*
  Feminino de *produtor*. Responsável (feminino) pelo financiamento e supervisão de uma produção.

  (adaptados das entradas no Aurélio)

(Como não existe a palavra *productrix, -īcis* no latim, parece que o sufixo *-triz* no português é (ou era) [produtivo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_%28linguistics%29). Em outras palavras, o sufixo é usado na formação de palavras novas, formando formas femininas de substantivos masculinos com sufixo *-tor* / *-dor*.)

Comment: Excelente resposta mais uma vez, parabéns! +1

Answer (score 5):

A maioria dos **substantivos masculinos que designam profissões**, principalmente aqueles que terminam em "o", passa para o feminino com a substituição de "o" por "a" ou simplesmente o acréscimo de "a", se terminarem em uma consoante.

- sapateiro/sapateir**a**
- costureiro/costureir**a**
- professor/professor**a**
- secretário/secretári**a**
- dançarino/dançarin**a**
- médico/médic**a**
- enfermeiro/enfermeir**a**

Outros substantivos formam o feminino com outros sufixos

- "ete" (garçon**ete**)
- "tisa" (poetisa, sacerdo**tisa**)
- "ã" (tabeli**ã**)

outros ainda formam o feminino com o acréscimo de **"triz"**.  É o caso de ator/atriz, imperador/imperatriz.  "meretriz" termina em "triz" mas não tem forma correspondente no masculino.  Ainda temos **o caso especial de "embaixador"** que admite as formas **"embaixadora"** (a mulher titular de um cargo na embaixada) e **"embaixatriz"** (a esposa do embaixador)

Por fim, também existem aquelas profissões que formam o feminino de forma totalmente irregular, aquelas que não variam em gênero (**o/a artista**), etc. Nâo há uma regra, é uma questão de terminação do masculino e do uso consagrado pelo povo.  Não tanto uma questão de etimologia. O estudante de Lingua Portuguesa tem que aprendê-los de acordo com a terminação do masculino, e depois estudar as exceções (é o caso de "ator/atriz"). [vide](http://ensinodoportugues.pbworks.com/w/page/10670411/G%C3%A9nero%20masculino%20e%20feminino)

Answer (score -1):

Imperadora é o feminino de Imperador.
Imperatriz, é a esposa do Imperador.
Atriz é a forma correta, embora não concorde.

Comment: Dizer que "*atriz* é a forma correta" não responde à pergunta. A pergunta é precisamente por que é que *atriz* é correto. Os dicionários dizem que *imperatriz* pode ser a soberana de um império (feminino de imperador) ou a esposa do imperador.