# É possível substituir atriz por atora?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Sabe-se que o feminino de *ator* é *atriz*. Porém, é possível, sem prejuízo à correção, substituí-lo por *atora*? Seria um exemplo de neologismo ou de incorreção?

Comment: Não, não é possível. *Atora*, apesar de existir, não é o feminino de ator. Mais sobre *atriz*: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/864/2759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é possível. A palavra *atora* tem significado diferente do que a palavra *atriz*:

> a·to·ra |ó|
>   substantivo feminino [Brasil]
>   Pedaço de pau cortado em
>   peças regulares; toro.

Fonte: [priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/atora)